# Unable to run robo3t?

Tags: command-line

I'm getting this error while running `robo3t` command.

```
root@vaibhav-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/bin# robo3t

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the application?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the libstdc++ .
Delete the following files and the program should run just fine.

```
rm ./bin/libstdc++*
```

Then run your program

```
./bin/robo3t
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below file(s) from **lib** folder and it should start working.

```
rm ./lib/libstdc++*
```